# Zend relationship - get the parent row

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I know there are some examples in the web, but doesn't work in my case.

I have a Category table with subcategories. One table 'category' that has id_father that's the id of the Parent Category.
My configuration is the following:

Application_Model_DbTable_Category:

```
protected $_referenceMap = array(
    'Application_Model_DbTable_Category' => array(
        'columns'           => 'id_father',
        'refColumns'        => 'id',
        'refTableClass'     => 'Application_Model_DbTable_Category'
));
```

CategoryMapper (I don't write the top code, anyway I retrieve a Category that has a parent in the db)

```
$row = $result->current(); 
echo $row->name;
$father = 'Non trovato';
$father = $row->findParentRow('Application_Model_DbTable_Category');
print_r($father);
```

This doesn't print anything... Is something wrong on my code? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create instance of class Application_Model_DbTable_Category

```
$row = $result->current(); 
echo $row->name;
$father = 'Non trovato';
$father = $row->findParentRow(new Application_Model_DbTable_Category());
print_r($father);
```

Comment: I loove you! Thanks! can you explain me why in the documentation they pass always a string as a parameter? :S

Comment: it as documentation bug @zend then .